# How to split a path in perl with full filename?

Tags: perl, path, split

I want to split a path can anyone help me?

My input is:

```
$getpath = "/u/project/path/file.name";
```

I want to split `/u/project/path` in one variable and `file.name` in other variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) can help you extract the informations you need (and is part of the core modules)

```
  my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($path);
```

Comment: Thank u.. Actually I've just started perl and learning things.. Thanks a lot for ur support !! :)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, there are many perl modules can do what you want, try searching on the CPAN.
Second, I suggest using File::Spec module. For example:

```
use File::Spec;
($volume,$directories,$file) = File::Spec->splitpath( $path );
```

then $directories will be "/u/project/path", and $file will be "file.name".

File::Spec module is capable of five operating systems: Unix(Linux), Mac, Win32, OS2, VMS.
And this module also offers tons of other file operations like catpath, updir, file_name_is_absolute, etc.
You don't need to change your codes on different systems.

Ref: [File::Spec](http://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aSpec)

Comment: Thank u.. Actually I've just started perl and learning things.. Thanks a lot for ur support !! :)

Comment: @Mak_Thareja You are welcome, and welcome to the fantastic Perl world :)

Comment: Ya it seems to be fantastic

Answer (score 2):

```
my($path, $file) = $getpath =~ m{(.+)/([^/]+)$};
```

There are nice cross platform modules for this too, see [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.018/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) and [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ASpec).

Comment: Thank u.. Actually I've just started perl and learning things.. Thanks a lot for ur support !! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
my $getpath = "/u/project/path/file.name";
my @arr=split /\//,$getpath;
my $filename=$arr[(scalar(@arr))-1]; #will give you the filename
my $path_no_filename= join "/",@arr[0..(scalar(@arr)-2)]; #will give everything except the filename
```

Comment: You can use negative subscripts to access an element from the end: `$filename = $arr[-1]`, and use implicit scalar context for arithmetic operators for the range: `$path = join '/', @arr[0..@arr-2]`. But it might be more elegant to say `$filename = pop @arr; $path = join '/', @arr`.

Comment: If one does not want to use modules, I think then this is the best way to learn programming. Thanks for ur support !! :)

Comment: I was just interested in the regex-based solution: I have to build names out of paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $f = Mojo::File->new($getpath);
print($f->dirname, "::", $f->basename);
```

Quick test :

```
> perl -Mojo -E 'my $f = f("/u/project/path/file.name"); say $f->dirname, "::", $f->basename' 
/u/project/path::file.name
```